# Loop starts from the beginning with second while loop on author.php

Tags: loop, author-template

I am using the same template for author.php and home/blog.php.

I have a loop split into 3 parts.

```
<?php

if(have_posts()): the_post;
  //do a thing
endif:

$i = 0;
while(have_posts()): the_post();
  //do three things
$i++; if ($i == 3): break; endif; 
endwhile;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
  //do the rest
endwhile;

?>
```

This seems to be working fine on the home/blog page but on the author.php, in the 2nd while loop, I'm getting posts starting from 1, when I shouldn't be getting any.

For this particular author I have 2 posts so I should be getting something like:

```
<?php

if(have_posts()): the_post();
  //post1
endif:

$i = 0;
while(have_posts()): the_post();
  //post2
$i++; if ($i == 3): break; endif; 
endwhile;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
  //no posts
endwhile;

?>
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
<?php

if(have_posts()): the_post();
  //post1
endif:

$i = 0;
while(have_posts()): the_post();
  //post2
$i++; if ($i == 3): break; endif; 
endwhile;

while(have_posts()): the_post();
  //post1 + post2
endwhile;

?>
```

What's up with my loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the loop is complete, `have_posts()` rewinds it back by [calling](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3533) the `rewind_posts()` method of the `$wp_query` object, see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L3533).

Here's another (more simple?) setup that you could try:

```
while( have_posts()): the_post();
   if ( 0 == $wp_query->current_post ): 
       // post 1   
   elseif ( 1 == $wp_query->current_post ): 
       // post 2      
   else:        
       // other posts   
   endif;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

where we use the `current_post` property of the global `$wp_query` object to keep the track of the current post.

Comment: It's difficult to see how this would work in my context. I have 3 sections, and I believe I need to come out of the loop because I don't that content repeating with every post. So I would need an `endif;` inbetween each statement?

Comment: If you must use the above setup, you can for example check the post count `$wp_query->post_count` before entering the while loops.

Comment: your rewind explanation helped me find a fix that I could understand :) `<?php if(in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue; ?>` it's messy I know.